# set connection in separate class file in c#

Tags: sql, connection-string

How to pass connection from separate class??

this is my connection class

```
class connectionCls
{
    public static SqlConnection openConnection()
    {
        string connectionString = "Server=tcp:****,1433;" +
            "Database=*******;User ID=********;Password=***********;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Her is my sql command class

```
class sqlCls 
{
    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO
    ***** VALUES(****) ", conn))
}
```

when i have connection and command at same class it works fine, 
but when i have separate class i stock when i try to pass "conn" from connectionCls to my sqlCls

Comment: You need to capture the connection in a variable. something like this --> 
`var conn = connectionCls.openConnection();`

Answer (score 1):

```
    class connectionCls
    {
        public static SqlConnection openConnection()
        {

            string connectionString = "Server=tcp:****,1433;" +
           "Database=*******;User ID=********; Password=***********; Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());
            return conn;
        }
    }
```

Call in sqlCls

```
        SqlConnection conn = connectionCls.openConnection();
        string insertStatement = @"INSERT INTO
                                  reportFormDataTable VALUES(@reportID ) ";

        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportID", reportID);
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new
   SqlConnection(&quot;Server=server_name;Database=database_name;uid=userid;password=password&quot;);
```